# ValueError: Can only save/restore ResourceVariables when executing eagerly, got type: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a rather involved tensorflow program, and I want to save the resulting session for later use. The program was written in v1 and im running it in v2, so i use tf.compat.v1 for everything.

When I try to save the session I get the above error, even though I verified that tf.compat.v1.executing_eagerly() returns True.
I assume the issue has something to do with the fact I'm using v1 from within v2.

There is a [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43422) about it, but no solution. And other threads that discuss the same problem offer the solution of running enable_eager_execution(), which I did to no avail.

Running TF 2.12.0 on Ubuntu v20.4.

Comment: The solution in the link describes that `tf.disable_v2_behavior()` work, but don't in your case?

Comment: Right, not working